# JavaScript works in Console not in code new Date(parseInt(<datestring>))

Tags: javascript, date, console, parseint

can anybody help and tell me why this

```
new Date(parseInt("1395427364000"))
```

works in the console but this

```
var testDate = new Date(parseInt("1395427364000"))
```

in the code gives me an invalid date

Comment: Can you expand upon what code you're using it with?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, but you should add a radix to the parseInt -> http://jsfiddle.net/oramat2f/

Comment: Use a 10 base for parseInt: `parseInt("1395427364000", 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console prints the return value of a statement. The return value of a `var x = someValue` statement is not the value. If you later just call `testDate` in the console, you'll indeed see its value.